# Forfiles Escaping with regular expression

Tags: for-loop, variables, curl, grep, expression

I'm using linux program in windows Environment (curl and grep)

This command works fine in dos shell and get result

```
curl --request POST "https://somesite/access_token" --user user:pass | grep -o -P -e "(?<=\"access_token\":\").+?(?=\")"
```

but If I try this script in batch to save result in a variable

```
for /f %%a in ('curl --request POST "https://somesite/access_token" --user user:pass ^| grep -o -P -e "(?<=\"access_token\":\").+?(?=\")"') do set "TOKEN=%%a"
```

I got this error:

**.+?(? was unexpected at this time.**

any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should include tags about your environment (which seems to be important in this question, more than tags expression and/or variables)

Comment: please explain better do you mean "tags", thank you